# Passwordless chef client bootstrapping

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, knife, chef-client

I am bit familiar with Chef and its bootstrapping techniques. I am trying to bootstrap my new chef-client/node without passing password

I tried below by generating a ssh key but still failing

`knife bootstrap MY_NODE_IP -x SERVER_ADMIN_USERNAME -i PATH_TO_KEY_FILE --sudo --node-name THE_NODE_NAME`

On triggering above command on Chef DK getting error as below

```
WARN: [SSH] PTY requested: stderr will be merged into stdout
WARN: [SSH] connection failed, terminating (#<Net::SSH::AuthenticationFailed: Authentication failed for user user@mynode>)
ERROR: Train::Transports::SSHFailed: SSH session could not be established
```

I also tried doing manual installation as per below instruction , but again a failure                        https://serverfault.com/questions/761167/how-to-manually-set-up-a-chef-node
I created a client manually, but I was unable to create a node in chef server manually. Please suggest

Getting network error as below

```
Networking Error:
-----------------
Error connecting to https://myserver/organizations/organization/nodes/mynode - Failed to open TCP connection to www.internet:8080 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)
```

Bootstrapping from my chef DK also throws an error

Is there a way to bootstrap linux chef client without using password from a windows chef DK?
Below is my Chef environment
**1.Chef Infra Client: 15.14.0**

**2.Chef Workstation 0.8.7.1**

**3.Chef-server 12.18.14**

Comment: If you can SSH to the node with `SERVER_ADMIN_USERNAME` and `PATH_TO_KEY_FILE`, bootstrap should work fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: Your problem is that your target node has no allowed_keys to allow key based login. That's a pure ssh configuration problem unrelated to chef.